# What's the meaning of "parent inline element"?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

With respect to `vertical-align`, W3C spec [says](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#strut):

> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline
> element, or to the strut of a parent block container element.

What's the meaning of `parent inline element` here? Is it the first inline element inside a container? If yes, why is it called "`parent`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best explained with an example, I think.

```css
.bar {
  vertical-align:-20px;
}
.baz, .qux {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
  <div>foo
    <span class="bar">bar
      <span class="baz">baz</span>
    </span>
    <span class="qux">qux</span>
  </div>
```

All the spans and text content are part of a single line box. The div establishes the inline formatting context, the line box and its strut.

The "foo" text sits on the baseline with respect to the strut's baseline.
The `.bar` span is offset with respect to the strut's baseline by 20px.
The `.baz` and `.qux` spans have the same styling, where the top of their upper half leading is aligned with the top of content area of their "parent". But you can see that they are not aligned with one another.

That's because the `.qux` span is aligned with respect to the strut, but the `.baz` is aligned with respect to its **parent inline element**, that is, the `.bar` span element.